# Powershell - refresh date in variable

Tags: powershell

My question is, how can I store date in variable, and then push there new date.
I'll explain my code:
-get today's date and substract it from last write time of file
-get amount of hours
-while last write time is greater or equal 1 hour inform to edit file
-get most recent last write time
-then sleep 10 seconds

The problem is that even if I edit file, loop still shows previous date. How can I make it work?

```
$file = get-childitem $input_users
   $time = (get-date)-$file.lastwritetime
   $hours = $time.hours

   while (($time.hours) -ge (1)){
         write-host -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor White  "$input was written to $hours hours ago, please edit it first"
         write-host -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor White  "Next check in 10 seconds."
         $time = (get-date)-$file.lastwritetime
                                }
```

Comment: Question should be moved to StackOverflow.

Comment: Meh, there are 302 PS questions here on SU. Scripting is a valid power user activity in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a new file object and recalculate the hours inside the loop:

```
$file = get-childitem $input_users
$time = (get-date)-$file.lastwritetime
$hours = $time.hours

while (($time.hours) -ge (1)){
    write-host -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor White  "$input was written to $hours hours ago, please edit it first"
    write-host -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor White  "Next check in 10 seconds."
    $file = Get-ChildItem $input_users
    $time = (Get-Date) - $file.LastWriteTime

}
```