# PowerShell: Refreshing date stored in a variable

Tags: variables, powershell, refresh

I have the following variable that is used in many of my scripts for logging:

`$uDate = get-date -format "ddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

Only problem is that the date is never refreshed and only shows the date/time when the variable was declared.

Comment: FYI, I searched everywhere on StackOverflow first and the closest thing I found was this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639063/powershell-refresh-date-in-variable

However this makes use of a loop which would indefinitely pause my script at the loop.

Comment: Perhaps an example of what you're trying to accomplish would help?

Comment: Sorry guys for the lack of information. It was really simple, just take the date/time plus some text and redirect it to text file to create a log. Re-used about 50 times through various scripts.

Comment: fyi..this is a great free ebook if your looking for a pretty thorough walk through of powershell: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/default.aspx

Comment: Funny you say that, I already use this online book and reference to it all the time. Great eBook!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not be done with a variable.  Variables should store data, not take actions.  So the right way to do this is to create a function that returns the current date in the format you want.

But... if you want to get really hack-tastic you can do this by setting a breakpoint on all reads to your variable.  The -Action of the breakpoint will reset the value of the variable to the current time.

```
$rightNow = Get-Date
Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable rightNow -Mode Read -Action { $global:rightNow = Get-Date }
```

Testing...

```
PS > $rightnow

Monday, August 20, 2012 11:46:04 AM

PS > $rightnow

Monday, August 20, 2012 11:46:09 AM
```

Comment: You are totally right, creating a function is the right way to go. Also, great rule of thumb: "Variables should store data, not take actions". Thank so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing more, maybe declare a newly defined function "now"?

```
function now()
{ 
  get-date -format "ddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
}
```

Or even using C# directly:

```
[datetime]::Now.ToString("ddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Okay, total brain fart here... I didn't even think about using a function. Love those easy solutions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Greg Wojan is right that to give you the best answer, we need to know what you are really trying to accomplish. I assume that you want a variable that will magically update itself every time that you try to use it. As far as I know, that isn't possible in PS. The closest I could think of would be to do something like this:

```
$uDate = {get-date -format "ddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
"The date now is $($uDate.Invoke())"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
"And now it is $($uDate.Invoke())"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to automatically update a variable on each use. Check out [New-TiedVariable](http://poshcode.org/2750) at PoshCode. Joel Bennett continues to impress. :-) It has its limitations, which are documented, but does work quite nicely.

Basically it's just a function wrapped around the answer provided by @latkin.